# How to create goto homepage link like in stackoverflow logo, it is picture of link or what?

Tags: html

I want to create logo that bring to the homepage, currently I using image as link, but I want to create similar like in this picture (like in **StackOverflow** logo)

When I right click it didn't bring `Save Image As...`
How to create this?

[image]

Comment: The SO logo in the header is an SVG sprite (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be) being used as a background image of a span. Examine the source code.

Comment: Firefox includes "Save Background Image As", though. If you want your logo to be unsaveable, you're out of luck. (Which is fine, because there's no good reason to try to prevent it.)

Comment: No I not mean that, I just want to know how or what method to create homepage logo like that, because Im still learning about web development,

Answer (score 0):

In the image you put in the question, you can also see "Inspect Element". By clicking on it, you will be shown the relevant HTML code, and you could reverse engineer it.
The trick is to put the image as a background-image of the container using css.